# Gremlin filter from previous step

Tags: java, gremlin, tinkerpop3

Currently working on a proof of concept for a recommendation engine.

**Example.**

```
public default GraphTraversal<S, Map<Object, Long>> suggestedFriends(Long limit) {
    return out("friendship")
        .as("myFriends")
        .out("friendship")
        .as("friendsOfFriends")
        .groupCount()
        .by("email")
        .order(Scope.local)
        .by(Column.values, Order.decr);
}
```

I'm trying to filter the first steps matched friends before the groupCount.

What would be the correct way of doing this?

**EDIT:**

Got the desired output agreggating the first step results, and filtering with `where` on the second one..

```
public default GraphTraversal<S, Map<Object, Long>> suggestedFriends(Long limit) {
    return out("friendship")
        .aggregate("x")
        .as("myFriends")
        .out("friendship")
        .as("friendsOfFriends")
        .where(P.without("x"))
        .groupCount()
        .by("email")
        .order(Scope.local)
        .by(Column.values, Order.decr)
        .limit(Scope.local, limit);
}
```

https://github.com/erneestoc/graph_example/blob/master/src/java/com/example/ExampleTraversalDsl.java#L24

Answer (score 1):

Answered on the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gremlin-users/lJrG3xTkoNo/2z_G8e7HAwAJ) already, but here it is again: The query, as you have it now, looks good, but you can also remove the labels as they don't add any value:

```
    return out("friendship").aggregate("x")
        .out("friendship")
            .where(P.without("x"))
        .groupCount()
        .by("email")
        .order(Scope.local)
        .by(Column.values, Order.decr)
            .limit(Scope.local, limit);
```